# Excel form control macro updates another sheet, Worksheet_Change event does not trigger

Tags: excel, vba, events, triggers, controls

I have an Excel ListBox (not ActiveX as these are causing display issues) with an Excel (dialog menu-driven) macro that outputs its value to a named range cell on a different sheet to the Listbox. In that sheet's code I have the below

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Debug.Print "ping"
End Sub
```

The macro event does not trigger when I click on the Listbox (therefore updating the named range cell value). I have verified that the macro executes when I directly update that sheet.

I assume the form control macro is circumnavigating the sheet event trigger. Am I right? Does anybody know an efficient workaround for this? I am stumped.

Thanks Kindly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can assign a macro to the ListBox as `ListBox1_Change` event (right click › assign macro) which will be executed on change of the ListBox value instead of `Worksheet_Change` then.

Probably that is why the `Worksheet_Change` is not triggered anymore when using the ListBox to change the cell value.

Comment: Perfect, thank you. I had a misnomer that assigning macros in the way you describe disables the functionality of the control. I was wrong

Comment: @Bezique you might consider accepting this as solution to the question so other users know that it is solved.

Comment: learning how to do this... I had already clicked the up arrow, but am told I need 15 rep before my votes will be displayed. Is there something else I should have done?